# Как в TWIG сделать проверку на количество записей в базе данных?

Tags: twig

Перед выполнением цикла мне необходимо сначала выполнить проверку:
Если записей много (больше 1) тогда выводим цикл, если меньше то тоже выводим но немного иначе.

`{% if records > 1 %}` не прокатывает))
Как это можно сделать? что-то не могу найти.

Пример кода, который нужно выполнить если записей больше 1

```
{% if record %}

    <h2>{{ record.name }}</h2>

{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Пример кода, который нужно выполнить если запись в базе одна.

```
{% if record %}

    <h1>{{ record.name }}</h2>

{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `{% if records > 1 %}` не прокатывает)) Как это можно сделать? что-то не
>   могу найти.

Если вы читали [документацию](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#control-structure), то вероятно могли заметить там такую управляющих конструкций и пример кода

```
{% if users|length > 0 %}
```

что в вашем случае будет выглядеть как

```
{% if records|length > 1 %}
```